# Clicar sobre área da página e fechar MENU

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando fazer esse script que feche o **MENU** quando clico em qualquer área do `main`.

O **MENU** abre a esquerda da página mobile. 
Mas como vocês podem ver o **MENU** está fora do `main`. Então não consegui fazer aquele código com `closest` verificando se algum elemento PAI possui a class `menu-in`.

```
    // Abre o Menu Mobile
    $('.open-menu-mobile').on('tap click', function(){
        $('main, nav.menu').addClass('menu-in');
    });

    nav.menu{
        position: absolute;
        width: 240px;
        background-color: #37474f;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0;
        left: -240px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        &.menu-in{
            transform: translateX(100%);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    {{-- MENU --}}
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="search">
            Procurar
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
            <li class="logo"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Onde Estamos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    {{-- MAIN --}}
    <main>
        {{--- Cabeçalho do Site Mobile --}}
        <header id="header">
            {!! Html::image('img/open-menu-mobile.png', 'Abrir Menu Mobile', ['class'=>'open-menu-mobile']) !!}
            <a href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}">
            </a>
        </header>

        @yield('content')
    </main>
```

---

Pessoal, dei uma mexida nesse código e agora está funcionando quase do jeito que preciso.

```
    // Abre o Menu Mobile
    $('.open-menu-mobile').on('tap click', function(e){
        $('main, nav.menu').stop(true, true).addClass('menu-in');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Clicar em alguma área do site e fechar MENU
    $(document).on('tap click', function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('.open-menu-mobile'))
            $("main, nav.menu").removeClass('menu-in');
    });
```

**O que acontece agora é o seguinte:**

Dentro do meu **MENU**, tenho LINKS e um campo de Busca. Quando clico nesses lugares, o **MENU** fecha também. Achei que usando o `stopPropagation()` resolveria isso.

Comment: Se você já sabe o nome da classe e acredito eu que ela seja única, porque você precisa usar o `closest`? Não pode procurar por ela diretamente? `$(".menu-in")`?

Comment: Não é única. Veja a função, jQuery. Eu aplico ela em dois lugares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui.

```
    // Clicar em alguma área do site e fechar MENU
    $('body').on('tap click', function(e){
        if(e.target !== $('nav.menu')[0] && $(e.target).closest('nav.menu').attr('class') != 'menu menu-in')
            $("main, nav.menu").removeClass('menu-in');
    });
```

Usei o `closest` para verificar se a classe do elemento pai é diferente do pai de onde estou clicando. Se sim, fecha o **MENU**.

Daí quando clico em um filho do elemento pai, não fecha o **MENU**, visto que a classe de seu elemento pai é = ao que eu determinei na condição.